# Join in Django views

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, django-views

I have 2 Models in my django app.
The corresponding tables for the two models are:

```
Table 1:
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Table2:
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| p_text        | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| p_slug        | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now what i want is to write the equivalent of the below query in my django view in the best way possible? The query i want to write is a simple join as:

```
select B.p_slug from Table1 A, Table2 B where A.post_id = B.id;
```

I tried but could not get it working. Any help please? How to implement the above query in Django views

The models are: Model1:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
class Model2(models.Model):
    p_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    p_slug = models.SlugField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: Table1 post_id is fk to Table2?

Comment: @Gocht have added the models

Comment: Can I assume that Model1 post is a FK to Model2 and that you get a value for B.id before the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `Model2.objects.filter(pk__in=Model1.objcts.values_list('post_id', flat=True)).values('p_slug')`. I hope it helps.